# Angular-Cli - How to structure scss?

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, angular-cli

I have been very frustrated with getting the styles to work as I want to in Angular-Cli. I just don't understand how you're expected to structure it.

This is my styles folder,

```
- styles
 -- components
 --- buttons.scss
 -- partials
 --- mixins.scss
 --- variables.scss
 -- main.scss
 -- styles.scss (default file)
```

in my `main.scss` file I have imported all the files I need through out the app.

```
@import './components/buttons.scss';
@import './partials/variables.scss';
@import './partials/mixins.scss';
```

and in my `app.component.ts`,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.html',
    styleUrls: [ '../styles/main.scss' ],
})
```

Everything works when I load the app. Great!
Then I add a new component `header.component.ts` and add `header.scss` into my styles folder.

```
-styles
 -- header
 --- header.scss
```

In the `header.component.ts` I set the stylesheet,

```
@Component({
        selector: 'app-header',
        templateUrl: './header.html',
        styleUrls: [ '../styles/header/header.scss' ],
    })
```

And I use this header inside `app.html`.

```
<div>
<app-header></app-header>
</div>
```

Now my browser is throwing all sorts of errors for missing variables because header.scss has referred to variables in `/partials/variables.scss`.

But hasn't main.scss where variables.scss is imported, loaded already by the time header.component.ts loads? I don't understand how it works!

All I want to do is load `variables.scss, mixins.scss, buttons.scss` first and be able to use the variables and mixins inside those where ever I want. How do I do that?

EDIT:
Do I have to import `variables.scss, mixins.scss, buttons.scss` in every component I make?

Comment: So, why you are not using any css-loader, sass-loader etc. Which can give you the actual css files.

Comment: browser don't understand `scss`, you have to provide `css` file to browser

Comment: @Jai Hi. Thank you for replying. I'm actually very very new to this. I'm not familiar with using a sass-loader. If you don't mind can you tell me what it does

Comment: @PankajParkar Hi. Thank you for your reply. I'm not sure how Angular-cli works, but styles do work on the browser. But it seems I have to import all my style files into every component I make to be able to refer to variables and such in another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to import variables.scss, mixins.scss, buttons.scss in every
>   component I make?

Yes, you need to import them when you want to use for example variables in header.scss
But be aware of importing defined styles in classes, because when you import classes for example two times, then it's added two times to your output styles..

Check this issue: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1094
For extending classes you can use sillent classes https://csswizardry.com/2014/01/extending-silent-classes-in-sass/

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. :)